# How can I compare two strings from a structure

Tags: c

I have a project for school in which I need to give the user the option to sort two students in Numerical or Alphabetical order. I already managed to do the first one (Numerical order), but I can't manage to understand how I can order them alphabetically.

The names of the students are given by the user and they are stored in the struct. When i try to use:

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name) < 0));
```

I get the error 'argument of type "bool" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*".

**This is the struct**

```
typedef struct
{
    int number;
    char name[10];
    char surname[10];
}num_nom_surname;
num_nom_surname *number_name_surname;
```

**this is the Alphabetical order**

```
if(number_name_surname[0].number > number_name_surname[1].number)
        { 
            for (i = number_of_students - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
                printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
            {
                printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
                printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
            }
        }
```

**And this is the one I need help**

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name) < 0));
        {

        }
```

**// EDIT //**

So now that I have done it, I have another question.
In order to print names alphabetically i need to make sure that the first names are different. 
Example:

If The first name is: **Mark Adele** and the second is: **Mark Boy**, how do I print them in order?

Here is the code:

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)) < 0) 
        {
            for (i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
            {
                printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
                printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            for (i = number_of_students - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                printf("\n Student N%c %5d - ", 167, number_name_surname[i].number);
                printf("Name: %s %s", number_name_surname[i].name, number_name_surname[i].surname);
            }
        }
        printf("\n Value of strcmp: %d", strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)));
```

Comment: It seems the parenthesis is misplaced. Try this: `strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)) < 0)`.

Comment: `bool`? are you really truly 100% sure you are using C language and a C compiler? This message is typical for a C++ compiler, in C it would be different.

Comment: @n.m. I am  using Visual Studio, but i already fixed it, it was parenthesis that were misplaced!

Comment: Visual Studio supports both C and C++ languages. Some programs are valid in both C and C++, but most are not. You may want to read about the difference between these languages in order to avoid potentially costly confusion in the future.

Comment: To be specific, here are [Microsoft C error](http://rextester.com/PJU39616) and [Microsoft C++ error](http://rextester.com/PAM43183).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parenthesis are off, you have

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name) < 0))
```

but you need;

```
if (strcmp((number_name_surname[0].name), (number_name_surname[1].name)) < 0)
```

Comment: Oh my god, Thanks! Also I cant use the ';' , my mistake as well

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, simplify.

```
char* name1 = number_name_surname[0].name;
char* name2 = number_name_surname[1].name;

int res = strcmp(name1, name2);

if (res < 0)
{
   ...
}
```